# Resiliency of data when going offline and reconnecting with breeze js and web api 2

Tags: angularjs, breeze, google-chrome-app, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building a HTML 5 app using AngularJS, BreezeJS, and connecting to a SQL DB via Web API 2 (using EF codefirst).

I choose BreezeJS for this project because there will be many times that the client will lose internet connectivity for long periods of time before being reconnected and I liked the simplicity that Breeze offers with being able to handle manage and store changes locally and then sync up later (via exportEntities and importEntities respectively).

**QUESTION**
Since I don't know when that loss of connectivity (or power outage, device shut down, etc) will happen should I structure my AngularJS services to always export entities to the local storage and THEN attempt a web api call to export it there or should I manage two entityManagers, one to handle local data and one to handle remote data while somehow keeping both of those entityManagers in sync?  I don't think I can rely on the cache because I can't guarantee that the user won't do something to clear it.

**EDIT**
I decided to scrap the HTML 5 app approach and go with a Chrome App instead (I was recently told that I can focus solely on targeting Chrome browsers).  I still have the same question as above, but now, I would like to add the question if anybody has built a chrome app with BreezeJS and found any issues (primarily permission/security issues) or if there is a "chrome app" centric way to handle the offline data situation.

Comment: why is this labelled as "google-chrome-app"?